# Different Links CSS Hover change a picture

Tags: css, hover

I would like a CSS hover affect for multiple links that affect the same image. If you look at this example site I have Repair, Sales, Upgrades and Data Recovery links. When you hover over any one of them I would like the image to their left to change. You can hover over the image currently there to see what I mean.

website: http://ctuchicago.squarespace.com/

Comment: You cannot use pure CSS to affect unrelated sections of the document tree.e.g. give `<div id="a"></div><div id="b">`, there is no way for a hover on A to actually change B's setup - they're not in a parent/child relationship. You will have to use JS to trap the hover events and change the images yourself.

Comment: Have I mis-understood the question?

Comment: @MarcB they *can be* in a parent child relationship and therefore this *can* be done with pure css.

Comment: @joseph: then the :hover class has to be on the first common parent of both elements. depending on the structure, that could be the `<body>` tag. not exactly useful.

Comment: @MarcB note that I said "can be".  That implies the markup needs changed.  My point was this can be done with css alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a box that contains the image and all of the links. Then when the box is hovered over the image will change. This doesn't get you exactly what you want - which is only hovering over the link changes the image, but I think it is close enough and far easier.

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/D5ZRs/

```
div:hover img { background: url('blah'); }

<div> 
  <img src="" />
  <a href="">Repair</a>
  <a href="">Sales</a>
</div>
```

Comment: depends what their browser requirements are, some older versions of IE only support `:hover` on `a` elements

Comment: Only IE6. Die IE6 die! IE6 is down to about 3% for US browser users. I don't think it worth the headache of supporting unless you have large mission critical customers. IE6 is for pirated versions of Windows in China. http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-US-monthly-201009-201108

Comment: second that! I don't personally support IE6 unless I absolutely HAVE to!

Comment: yeah because it`s just an headache !

Comment: I think this is the best solution ! pretty clever ! .. Thank you very much. It`s the easiest / most efficient way !

Answer (score 1):

Put the image inside the `a` tag. Then use `position: relative` to position the image...

for example

```
a img{
   position: relative;
   left: -50px;
}
```

Comment: also don't forget to put the other tags inside the `<a>` tag as Alon said

Comment: right idea, but it appears the image isn't in an img tag but is the background property of the anchor.

Comment: ohh! sorry missed that. Then you can just move the other tags into the anchor, use `background-positon: left` `padding-left: 50px`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `<p>`, and `<h3>` tags inside the `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work... partially XD

```
<div class="frontdiv fblankd">
    <a href="/audio-video" id="hav" style="width: auto;">
        <div style="
            height: 80px;
            margin-left: 81px;
            background: white;
            color: black;
        ">
            <h3>AUDIO / VIDEO</h3>
            <p><a href="#music">Music Server</a>, <a href="#theatre">Home Theatre</a>, <a href="#zone">Zone Systems</a>, <a href="#remote">Universal Remote Control</a></p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

The basic idea is to have your content in the a tag (like ever body has been saying).

What I've done with the styling is set the anchor to width:auto and wrapped the content in a div.  this div I then gave a height of 80px, left margin of 81px, background of white and font color of black.

Comment: Big problem is that he actually wants each of those child links to be unique. They aren't currently links at all, but will be.

Comment: @mrtsherman I... don't understand what you mean.  Where was that specified?

Comment: @mrtsherman Oh I see what you mean.  The links can be added in the wrapper like normal.  See my edited answer.

Comment: Thats smart but guys come on putting 2 <a> tags inside of each other is not a good idea. =)